# Target Priority for Turrets?

Tags: league-of-legends

Obviously, turrets prioritize minions unless a friendly champ takes damage from an enemy champ within the turret's range, and if there are no minions the turret will target the first enemy champ to come within range. My question is this - if there are multiple enemy champs within range as the last friendly minion dies, how does the turret prioritize the enemy champs? Is it random, or is there some factor that affects which enemy champ the turret will start attacking first?

Answer (score 11):

The League of Legends site covers this in [this article](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/learn/gameplay/minions-and-turrets).  The priority of turrets is as follows (emphasis mine):

> - An enemy champion designated by a call for help from an allied champion.
> - An enemy minion designated by a call for help from an allied champion.
> - The closest enemy minion.
> - **The closest enemy Champion.**
>
> Note: Any time a champion takes damage near a friendly turret, it will
>   immediately try to attack the aggressor unless otherwise occupied with
>   an enemy champion.

In regards to your question, the turret will target the closest enemy champion

Comment: I suppose I'll have to watch more closely the next time I see this situation. The questiong stemmed from seeing, on several occasions, a turret ignore a melee champ attacking the base of the turret to focus on a ranged champ instead. According to what you've said, the ranged champ must have been tagged with a call for help - which makes sense, seeing as how that'd most likely be the carry, who are routinely tagged by teammates. Thanks for shedding some light on that for me.

Comment: @Strife7x Glad I could help.  I'll remove my emphasis, since I had originally assumed you were already aware of attacking minions drawing aggro as well.

Comment: @DaveMcClelland It should be noted that a 'Call for help' is not a ping but rather something that Champions and minions do automatically when they are attacked.  Also, the priority list for turrets is smaller than that of minions, and it may be worth separating instead of combining.  The list you provided is for minions, and although it includes the turret list(a subset), the question asked for turret :) good find though

Comment: @BrianColvin Wow, good call.  I hadn't scrolled all the way down the page to see the other list :).  I'll update the answer, thanks!